# Android java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.myapp.code.WordDescription.onRestart(WordDescription.java:685)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestart(Instrumentation.java:1245)
at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:3892)
at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3911)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2424)
```

I don't really understand why I keep getting error on WordDescription.onRestart.
Many are complaining of force close issues. Any clue on how to fix this? Thanks

I think this one is related ..

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] aListText;
    private final String [] meaningText;

    public MyArrayAdapter(Activity context, String[] wordText, String[] meaningText) {
        super(context, R.layout.desclist2, wordText);
        this.context=context;
        this.aListText= wordText;
        this.meaningText=meaningText;
    }
} // ..... 

@Override
public void onRestart(){
    super.onRestart();
    clickFlag = false;
    clickWordFlag = false;
    myArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  <-- line 685
}
Handler handler = new Handler(){  <-- line 709
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg){
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        if{ ....
        }else{
            myArrayAdapter = new MyArrayAdapter(WordDescription.this, wordArray, meaningArray);
            listView.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);
        }

    }
```

Comment: where myArrayAdapter object is created?

Comment: you sould not call notifyDataSetChanged in MyArrayAdapter class.insted call it in activity where you have created object of it.

Comment: Sorry I didn't copy it right.. the MyArrayAdapter class ends before onRestart. does this mean I need to call it elsewhere or it's a lack of if(myArrayAdapter != null) as mentioned by Chandra Sekhar, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
myArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

to

```
if(myArrayAdapter != null)
      myArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I strongly suggest you to do what **Vipul Shah** told in his comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this...

```
myArrayAdapter = new MyArrayAdapter(WordDescription.this, wordArray, meaningArray);
listView.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);
if(myArrayAdapter != null){
      myArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```